# Boost deadline_timer is not generating event when i am using expire_at?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, timer, boost-asio

class header file
//dividandconquer.h

```
#ifndef DIVIDANDCONQUER_H
#define DIVIDANDCONQUER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/date.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;


class dividandconquer
{
public:
    dividandconquer(boost::asio::io_service& io);
    int lb =0;
    int ub =1000;
    int mb =0;
    ptime t1;
    ptime finaltimer;
    void  reset(int);

     void print();
private:
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
  int count_;
};

#endif // DIVIDANDCONQUER_H
```

inside constructor i am trying to trigger timer at specific time(using expire_at) but its not working. But if i am using expires_from_now it works fine.

File name :dividandconquer.cpp

```
#include "dividandconquer.h"

dividandconquer::dividandconquer(boost::asio::io_service& io)
    : timer_(io),
      count_(0)
  {
    t1=ptime( (boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day()), hours(15)+minutes(12));
    timer_.expires_at(t1);
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&dividandconquer::print, this));

  }
void dividandconquer::reset(int upordown)// 0 means lowebound 1 means uperbound
{
    if (mb>0)
    {
        if (0==upordown)
        {    mb=(lb+ub)/2;
            ub=mb;
        }
        else
        {
            mb=(ub-lb)/2;
            lb=mb;
        }

    }
}
void dividandconquer::print()
{
  if (count_ < 5)
  {
    std::cout << count_ << "\n";
    ++count_;

  //timer_.expires_at(timer_.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
//  timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print, this));
  }
}
```

main file

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "dividandconquer.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   boost::asio::io_service io;
   dividandconquer d1(io);
   io.run();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that `asio::deadline_timer` expects absolute timepoints in UTC but `gregorian::day_clock::local_day()` returns the *local* date without any time component; I believe this is a working (and reduced) version of what you're looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

using namespace boost::posix_time;
using boost::system::error_code;

struct dividandconquer {
    explicit dividandconquer(boost::asio::io_service& io) : timer_(io) {
        timer_.expires_at(microsec_clock::universal_time() + milliseconds(500));
        timer_.async_wait([this](error_code const&){ print(); });
    }

    void print() {
        if (count_ < 5) {
            std::cout
                << microsec_clock::universal_time().time_of_day().ticks()
                << " :: " << count_++ << '\n';

            timer_.expires_at(timer_.expires_at() + milliseconds(500));
            timer_.async_wait([this](error_code const&){ print(); });
        }
    }

private:
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
    int count_{};
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    dividandconquer d1{io};
    io.run();
}
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34d382a28d9d1e5c)**</kbd>

(Or see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b55b49dbf40c96e4) if you really want to stick with `bind` over using a lambda.)

Since you're using C++11, it's best to avoid involving Boost.Date_Time in any way and just use the standard library instead:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>

using namespace std::chrono;

struct dividandconquer {
    explicit dividandconquer(boost::asio::io_service& io) : timer_(io) {
        timer_.expires_at(steady_clock::now() + milliseconds(500));
        timer_.async_wait([this](error_code const&){ print(); });
    }

    void print() {
        if (count_ < 5) {
            std::cout
                << steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()
                << " :: " << count_++ << '\n';

            timer_.expires_at(timer_.expires_at() + milliseconds(500));
            timer_.async_wait([this](error_code const&){ print(); });
        }
    }

private:
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
    int count_{};
};
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/258d10653cbc5a1e)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for the help. as i am from india (utc +5:30) so i changed my code to                 t1=ptime( (boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day()), hours(15)+minutes(12)-hours(5)-hours(30)); this is working fine for me . your answer is very helpful thanks again.

Comment: @Rsvay : What is your intent with that code? Is it to get a timepoint for today at 15:12, or to get a timepoint for 15h12m from now? If the former, it is indeed correct. :-] But again, I recommend not using `boost::gregorian` here at all; whatever you're trying to accomplish can be done with `<chrono>`, which should be preferred. If you must stick with `boost::gregorian`, then use `universal_day` instead of `local_day` so you don't have to adjust to UTC manually: `t1=ptime( (boost::gregorian::day_clock::universal_day()), hours(15)+minutes(12));`